# How can i get all the records from view when view doesn't have primary key or composite unique primary key in spring data JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm in very crunch situation where I need to query the view which doesn't have the primary key. Here is the sample view.
[image]

I need to get the information using the memberID. When i use repository to retrieve the data from view, it only returns below

[image]

I know we can use the composite primary key but primary key can not be null so can not iunclude Demo_value column in compoiste Primary key.

Comment: Why don't you add custom method to the repository - `findByMemberID(memberId)`?

Comment: Just write a query and map the result. Don't try to shoehorn something into an entity that really isn't.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.